# Starting MVC Web Api from Stateful Service Fabric Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am very new in .net and service fabric world do my doubt may seem very basic but please bear with me.

So i want to have a stateful service fabric application in which i want to host the Web API. i know the option of "Stateful ASP.net core" but i have dependency on some packages which dont support .net core so i cant use it.

So what i have done is create a stateful .net application and a separate web application in the same solution. I dont know what configuration i need to do to start the web application on from the service fabric app.

I searched a lot about this but i could not find any doc/reference which can help me with this so i have to post this question here. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app)? [Code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?products=azure-service-fabric) and [this repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-quickstart)

Comment: Thanks Roman Marusyk. All these samples and docs refer Asp.Net core. But i wanted to have .net 4.x.